# Ansible Conditional Role Dependencies

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a question that has been bugging me for quite some time and I cannot find a proper way to handle it. I read all the documentation I could get, but I cannot find a satisfying answer.

Consider my situation: I have several Ansible roles which set up web applications (classical LAMP stack). Depending on whether I want to use self signed certificates or valid ones from LetsEncrypt I want to have a role pulled and run as a dependency, which in turn acquires certificates from LetsEncrypt.

What I did in the past was this, which does the job:

```
dependencies:
  - { role: thorian93.ansible_role_certbot, when: nextcloud_create_self_signed_cert == "false" }
```

The problem is: The Ansible Galaxy does not appreciate this syntax and rejects the import.

After reading the docs I changed the syntax to the following:

```
dependencies:
  - name: thorian93.ansible_role_certbot
    version: master
```

This syntax (along others of course) works and can be imported, but you probably have spotted my problem: The conditional is gone.

So plain and simple: Can anyone point to a possible solution or is this just not possible?

Comment: You can conditionally [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-role-load-and-execute-a-role). Wouldn't this solve the problem?

Comment: This is a little awkward, but yes, that works. I still would like to have the role installed conditionally, as this way the play will fail if the user did not install the dependent role in advance. But if you formulate your comment as an answer I am happy ti accept it.

Comment: Yeah, I can see where you are pointing at, but I just miss the possibility to declare the conditional dependency in the meta data. Will see if I get the time to build your suggestion and post it. For now the `include_role` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*Depending on whether I want to use self-signed certificates or valid ones from LetsEncrypt I want to have a role pulled and run as a dependency, ...*"**

A: Create a dictionary of issuers and required roles. Depending on the issuer install and include the roles. For example

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    my_roles_path: "$HOME/.ansible/roles"
    my_roles:
      Let's Encrypt Authority X3: [role1, role2, role3]
      default: [role91, role92, role93]
  tasks:
    - command:
        cmd: "ansible-galaxy install {{ item }}"
        creates: "{{ my_roles_path }}/{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_roles[issuer_CN|default('default')] }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_roles[issuer_CN|default('default')] }}"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>